# how to replace a value in a json file with jq?

Tags: json, jq, edit

I have a json that has the following structure

```
[{
    "model": "about.term",
    "pk": 20202,
    "fields": {
        "term": "Summer",
        "year": 2020
    }
},
{
    "model": "about.term",
    "pk": 20203,
    "fields": {
        "term": "Fall",
        "year": 2020
    }
},
{
    "model": "about.officer",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
        "position": "President",
        "term_position_number": 0,
        "name": "Person 1",
        "start_date": "1984-01-01T00:00:00",
        "sfuid": "",
        "sfu_email_alias": "",
        "phone_number": 11111111111,
        "github_username": "",
        "gmail": "",
        "course1": "",
        "course2": "",
        "language1": "",
        "language2": "",
        "bio": "",
        "image": "about_static/exec-photos/stockPhoto.jpg",
        "elected_term": 19841,
        "sfu_officer_mailing_list_email": "NONE"
    }
},
{
    "model": "about.officer",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
        "position": "Vice President",
        "term_position_number": 1,
        "name": "Person 2",
        "start_date": "1984-01-01T00:00:00",
        "sfuid": "",
        "sfu_email_alias": "",
        "phone_number": 2222222222222,
        "github_username": "",
        "gmail": "",
        "course1": "",
        "course2": "",
        "language1": "",
        "language2": "",
        "bio": "",
        "image": "about_static/exec-photos/stockPhoto.jpg",
        "elected_term": 19841,
        "sfu_officer_mailing_list_email": "NONE"
    }
},
{
    "model": "about.officer",
    "pk": 3,
    "fields": {
        "position": "Treasurer",
        "term_position_number": 2,
        "name": "Person 3",
        "start_date": "1984-01-01T00:00:00",
        "sfuid": "",
        "sfu_email_alias": "",
        "phone_number": 3333333333,
        "github_username": "",
        "gmail": "",
        "course1": "",
        "course2": "",
        "language1": "",
        "language2": "",
        "bio": "",
        "image": "about_static/exec-photos/stockPhoto.jpg",
        "elected_term": 19841,
        "sfu_officer_mailing_list_email": "NONE"
    }
},
{
    "model": "about.officer",
    "pk": 4,
    "fields": {
        "position": "Secretary",
        "term_position_number": 3,
        "name": "Person 4",
        "start_date": "1984-01-01T00:00:00",
        "sfuid": "",
        "sfu_email_alias": "",
        "phone_number": 444444444444,
        "github_username": "",
        "gmail": "",
        "course1": "",
        "course2": "",
        "language1": "",
        "language2": "",
        "bio": "",
        "image": "about_static/exec-photos/stockPhoto.jpg",
        "elected_term": 19841,
        "sfu_officer_mailing_list_email": "NONE"
    }
}]
```

how can I change it with bash `jq` command so that it has the exact same data, structure and indentation but the values for key `sfuid` become `sfuid`, `sfu_email_alias` become `sfu_email_alias`, `phone_number` become `0`, `github_username` become `github_username` and `gmail` become `gmail`.

basically, I want to end up with this file

```
[{
    "model": "about.term",
    "pk": 20202,
    "fields": {
        "term": "Summer",
        "year": 2020
    }
},
{
    "model": "about.term",
    "pk": 20203,
    "fields": {
        "term": "Fall",
        "year": 2020
    }
},
{
    "model": "about.officer",
    "pk": 1,
    "fields": {
        "position": "President",
        "term_position_number": 0,
        "name": "Person 1",
        "start_date": "1984-01-01T00:00:00",
        "sfuid": "sfuid",
        "sfu_email_alias": "sfu_email_alias",
        "phone_number": 0,
        "github_username": "github_username",
        "gmail": "gmail",
        "course1": "",
        "course2": "",
        "language1": "",
        "language2": "",
        "bio": "",
        "image": "about_static/exec-photos/stockPhoto.jpg",
        "elected_term": 19841,
        "sfu_officer_mailing_list_email": "NONE"
    }
},
{
    "model": "about.officer",
    "pk": 2,
    "fields": {
        "position": "Vice President",
        "term_position_number": 1,
        "name": "Person 2",
        "start_date": "1984-01-01T00:00:00",
        "sfuid": "sfuid",
        "sfu_email_alias": "sfu_email_alias",
        "phone_number": 0,
        "github_username": "github_username",
        "gmail": "gmail",
        "course1": "",
        "course2": "",
        "language1": "",
        "language2": "",
        "bio": "",
        "image": "about_static/exec-photos/stockPhoto.jpg",
        "elected_term": 19841,
        "sfu_officer_mailing_list_email": "NONE"
    }
},
{
    "model": "about.officer",
    "pk": 3,
    "fields": {
        "position": "Treasurer",
        "term_position_number": 2,
        "name": "Person 3",
        "start_date": "1984-01-01T00:00:00",
        "sfuid": "sfuid",
        "sfu_email_alias": "sfu_email_alias",
        "phone_number": 0,
        "github_username": "github_username",
        "gmail": "gmail",
        "course1": "",
        "course2": "",
        "language1": "",
        "language2": "",
        "bio": "",
        "image": "about_static/exec-photos/stockPhoto.jpg",
        "elected_term": 19841,
        "sfu_officer_mailing_list_email": "NONE"
    }
},
{
    "model": "about.officer",
    "pk": 4,
    "fields": {
        "position": "Secretary",
        "term_position_number": 3,
        "name": "Person 4",
        "start_date": "1984-01-01T00:00:00",
        "sfuid": "sfuid",
        "sfu_email_alias": "sfu_email_alias",
        "phone_number": 0,
        "github_username": "github_username",
        "gmail": "gmail",
        "course1": "",
        "course2": "",
        "language1": "",
        "language2": "",
        "bio": "",
        "image": "about_static/exec-photos/stockPhoto.jpg",
        "elected_term": 19841,
        "sfu_officer_mailing_list_email": "NONE"
    }
}]
```

Comment: Neither the shown input nor the shown expected output is valid JSON.  Can we assume these should be valid JSON?  Also, since SO is not a free programming service, it is usual for questions to include some details (e.g. failed attempts) that serve to focus the question.  See [mcve] for guidelines.

Comment: 1. how is that not a valid JSON? 2. I know that it is usual for question to have failed attempts but I am completely hopeless with jq and couldn't figure out how to even do a failed attempt.

Comment: You can use `jsonlint.com` or jq itself to check for validity.  See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jq/info for further information. p.s. I did not "vote" to close the Q. If you want to avoid it being closed, though, I'd suggest you address the two issues I raised.

Comment: I added the square brackets. I guess I had just assumed that the fact that it was an array was implied. my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the input is valid JSON and that valid JSON is acceptable as output,
the following jq program will perform the required transformations:

```
map( reduce ("sfuid", "sfu_email_alias", "github_username", "gmail") as $k (.;
         if .fields[$k] then .fields[$k] = $k else . end)
       | if .fields.phone_number then .fields.phone_number = 0 else . end )
```

Using `reduce` here is of course in support of "DRY".  If `reduce` is unfamiliar to you, you can think of it as a kind of `for` loop.

#### DRY-er

```
def update($PATH; VALUE):
  . as $in
  | if ($PATH | select(IN($in|paths)) // null) 
    then setpath($PATH;VALUE) else . end;

map( reduce ("sfuid", "sfu_email_alias", "github_username", "gmail") as $k (.;
         update( ["fields", $k]; $k )
       | update( ["fields", "phone_number"]; 0) ))
```

Comment: I do not see `jq` anywhere in that answer, how is it a jq program?

Comment: The answer is in the form of a jq program.  You would run it with the jq processor. See e.g. https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/